# String.Split() using VbCrLf doesn't work but replacing VbCr with "" first then splitting on VbLf does work. Why?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, split, carriage-return, linefeed

I have an embedded text file as a Resource. The content is:

```
Apple
Pear
Orange
```

I am trying to pull this into a `List(Of String)` but the Carriage Return and Line Feed characters are messing it up.
For example I try this:

```
Dim myNames As List(Of String) = My.Resources.TreeNames.Split(CChar(vbCrLf)).ToList
```

But the line feed character is being passed through:

```
"Apple"
vbLf & "Pear"
vbLf & "Orange"
```

so I try it using the environment variable:

```
Dim myNames As List(Of String) = My.Resources.TreeNames.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine)).ToList
```

But that results in the exact same output.
So I try splitting it on the line feed character:

```
Dim myNames As List(Of String) = My.Resources.TreeNames.Split(CChar(vbLf)).ToList
```

And now the carriage return character is being passed through:

```
"Apple" & vbCr
"Pear" & vbCr
"Orange"
```

So the only way I got this to work is by first replacing the `vbCr` with nothing then splitting on the left over `vbLf`:

```
Dim myNames As List(Of String) = Replace(My.Resources.TreeNames, vbCr, "").Split(CChar(vbLf)).ToList
```

Can anyone explain why?  If I pull the file in directly to a string using this:

```
Dim myNames as String = My.Resources.TreeNames
```

I get:

```
"Apple" & vbCrLf & "Pear" & vbCrLf & "Orange"
```

Why is split not working properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Docs about [CChar(<expression>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions):

> Any valid Char or String expression; **only first character of a String
> is converted**; value can be 0 through 65535 (unsigned)

So `CChar(vbCrLf)` returns just `VbCr` (`\r` - `&H0D`)

Since you're now splitting the source string on just `VbCr`, the Line Feed, `VbLf` (`\n` - `&H0A`), remains.

You need the overload of [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) that accepts an array of Strings or Chars:
<sub>Note that `vbCrLf` is a String Type, so are `VbCr` and `VbLf`</sub>

```
Dim res = My.Resources.TreeNames
' As an array of String
Dim myNames = res.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
'Or
Dim myNames = res.Split({vbCr, VbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
```

Or as an array of Chars:

```
Dim myNames = res.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
' Or
Dim myNames = res.Split({ChrW(13), ChrW(10)}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
```

[StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions) is used to remove empty lines generated by splitting on multiple contiguous chars.
Without it, using your sample string - 3 items separated by Carriage Return + Line Feed - you would get an array of 5 elements instead of 3, including 2 empty elements.

Comment: Thank-you very much @Jimi, your explanation makes sense and I suppose I should have thought about that with the CChar (how would it know to take multiple characters). I used the `{vbCr, VbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` example and not only does it work it looks a lot better then my workaround using the replace function.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the VB constants. Instead, you should be using the Environment.NewLine property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline

Per the documentation:

> The property value of NewLine is a constant customized specifically
> for the current platform and implementation of the .NET Framework.

Usage:

```vb
Dim myNames = My.Resources.TreeNames.Split(Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: I did try that initially as detailed in my question but it also doesn't work.  I did accept another answer that did work well.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could skip .Split altogether and just

```
Dim LinesList = File.ReadAllLines("txtFruit.txt").ToList
```

With Option Infer on hold your cursor over LinesList and you will see that it is a strongly typed `List(Of String)`